# get http //localhost/ 500 (internal server error) laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, controller

Trying to 'get' the value from local database, but it doesn't work.

create.blade.php ajax script

```
<script>
    $('#viajes').on('change', function() {
        
            var opcionSeleccionada = this.value;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/viajes/' + opcionSeleccionada,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    document.getElementById('dia1').value = data.dia1;
                    document.getElementById('salida').value = data.salida;
                    document.getElementById('observacion').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('dia2').value = data.dia2;
                    document.getElementById('llegada').value = data.llegada;
                    document.getElementById('observacion2').value = '';
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                    console.error('Error en la petición AJAX: ' + error);
                    alert('Ocurrió un error al obtener los datos del viaje seleccionado. Por favor, intenta nuevamente más tarde.');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Route

```
    Route::get('viajes/{id}', [DashboardController::class, 'getInfo'])
        ->middleware('auth:admin')
        ->name('create3');
```

Controller

```
    public function getInfo($id)
    {      
        $viaje_inicial = ViajeInicial::find($id);
       
        if ($viaje_inicial) {
            // Construye la respuesta HTTP con los datos del viaje
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $viaje_inicial
            ]);
        } else {
            // Si no se encontró el viaje, devuelve una respuesta de error
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'El viaje no fue encontrado.'
            ], 404);
        }
    }
```

It seems to me that the route is correct, however I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBYYq.png)

Comment: What do your Laravel logs say? Is there a response body to accompany the 500 status (use your browser dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect)?

Comment: please add more details about your error. put response from browser network panel or put laravel logs here. thanafter we can helps you something

Comment: Well I was looking at the browser network panel and laravel logs. I had an issue in the controller and in the way I assigned the data within the script, but I managed to fix it and it works now. Thank you for your replies